# Could Mozilla MaintenanceService be used by an other program to avoid permission problems on Program File?

Tags: windows, firefox, uac

While updating my Firefox, I discovered that no permission was asked. Frist, I thought that something went wrong. But I quickly discover that they have [a service](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Windows_Service_Silent_Update) to launch the update in session 0.

Could this service be used by an other program to bypass some security? Could it become a back door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be possible to use the service to bypass some security e.g. to elevate privileges. Everything else is treated as a bug. Unfortunately there were a bunch of bugs in the past (for example CVE-2017-7760, CVE-2016-5253, CVE-2015-4505) which allow a local attacker to elevate privileges via the mozilla maintenance service.

If you are worried about this you can uninstall the service. In this case for further updates a fallback is used which use an elevation prompt.